# Dynamic title for specific component Angular

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Im using Angular 8 with Java Spring server side. Now this is my routing

```
{ 
  component: IndexComp
  path: "index"
},
{ 
  component: BlogComp
  path: "blog"
},
{ 
  component: ProductComp
  path: "product/:id"
},
```

Default title is "Shop", and used in Blog and Index page. But in Product page, the title is from server (maybe Iphone7, Iphone8, Skirt,... depend on data from server). I want to know how to change the title in Product page, tks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at `Title` from `@angular/platform-browser`.

You can inject it in the component and use `setTitle('You title string here')`

E.g.:

```
  constructor(private readonly titleService: Title) {
    const title = 'Shop'; // get title data from the server
    this.titleService.setTitle(title);
  }
```

*UPD:* based on this you can make it where ever you want: in resolver/component/service etc.

---

*UPD:* according to the route: you can make smth like that in AppComponent, for example

```
  constructor(private readonly titleService: Title,
              private readonly router: Router) {
    this.router.events.subscribe(route => {
      if (route instanceof NavigationEnd && route.urlAfterRedirects !== '/product') {
        const title = 'Dynamic Title String Here';
        this.titleService.setTitle(title);
      } else {
        const title = 'Default Title String Here';
        this.titleService.setTitle(title);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Tks but only 1 component need dynamic title in this case (product), what happens if I have n another component (index1, index2, ... index n), set title for each comp. I need another way.

Comment: Something like "if routing != product" -> "setTitle(title)"

Comment: @ThangHoang I've updated the answer with an example

Answer (score -1):

You can use this easiest way of routing as following...

```
 {
    path: 'Here/Your/Path',
    component: YourComponent,
    data: { title: "This is my title" },
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
 }
```

1. In Your component

```
this.route.data.subscribe(res => this.appComponent.title = res['title']);
```

2. In App component

```
//initialize variable
title: string = '';
```

Use this title variable in your header of the page.

I hope this is helpful for you. :)

Comment: This will cause ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError. NG0100